# Yii узнать id textfield?

Tags: php, yii

Создаю поля таким образом:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++)
{
    echo CHtml::label($rows[$i]['name'], $rows[$i]['name']);
    echo CHtml::textField('elem[]','',array('id'=>$rows[$i]['name']));
}
```

И в контролере:

```
foreach($_POST['elem'] as $check)
{
    $Ids = $_POST['elem'];
};
```

Так вот я получаю:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "231"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "4"
}
```

А как узнать id поля?

Comment: Какое id? Которое задали в качестве атрибута: `array('id'=>$rows[$i]['name'])`?

Comment: У вас цикл при каждой итерации вызывает `count($rows)`. Исправьте:  `for($i = 0, $cnt = count($rows); $i < $cnt; $i++) {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хоть и криво, но работает

*_form*

```
   echo CHtml::textField("elem[$id][val][]", $val, array('id' => $rows[$i]['name']));
```

В контроллере:

```
 $Ids = $_POST['elem'];
 echo '<pre>';
 var_dump($Ids);
```

И получаю:

```
    array(10) {  
    [4]=>  
    array(1) {     
    ["val"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "10000"
    }
  }
  [3]=>   
  array(1) {
    ["val"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "351"
    }
  }
  [5]=>  
  array(1) {
    ["val"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "100"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим Вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку "Опубликовать ответ" следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы.